# Convertir string a type date

Tags: javascript, php, base-de-datos

Mi problema es que recupero la fecha de mi base de datos en tipo string y la tengo de convertir a date, pero haciendo un console log de la variable data transformada a type date la respuesta es Nan.

Alguin me puede ayudar?

[image: Imagen del console log]

```
$(document).on("click", ".btnEditar", function(){

fila = $(this).closest("tr");
id = parseInt(fila.find('td:eq(0)').text());
nom = fila.find('td:eq(1)').text();
apellidos = fila.find('td:eq(2)').text();
email = fila.find('td:eq(3)').text();
telefon = fila.find('td:eq(4)').text();
persones = parseInt(fila.find('td:eq(5)').text());
dataBD = fila.find('td:eq(6)').text();
data = Date.parse(dataBD);
hora = fila.find('td:eq(7)').text();

console.log(dataBD,data);

$("#nom").val(nom);
$("#apellidos").val(apellidos);
$("#email").val(email);
$("#telefon").val(telefon);
$("#persones").val(persones);
$("#data").val(data);
$("#hora").val(hora);
opcion = 2; //editar
```

});

La respuesta del data = Date(dataBD); =
Sat Dec 17 2022 19:52:02 GMT+0100 (Hora estàndard del Centre d’Europa)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Que contiene la fila fila.find('td:eq(6)').text();?, en otra palabra ¿Que contiene dataBD?

Comment: La fecha en formato string. Esta en la imagen de captura de pantalla

Comment: Je, descuido mio. Dame un momento para revisar la documentación de Date

Comment: Intenta hacer data = Date(dataBD);

Comment: Me devuelve la fecha de hoy el data = Date(dataBD); Sat Dec 17 2022 19:52:02 GMT+0100 (Hora estàndard del Centre d’Europa)

Comment: Joel disculpa error mio, es: data=new Date(dataBD); .

Comment: Invalid Date me devuelve.

Comment: que raro, en la consola del navegador me devuelve la fecha que es.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141388/discussion-between-daniel-briceno-and-joel-valor).

Answer (score 2):

El problema se debe a que quieres crear una instancia Date usando la función [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) que devuelve el tiempo transcurrido desde el 1 enero en milisegundo, la solucion seria llamar al constructor de `Date`:

```js
var dateBD="29-12-2022";
var data=new Date(dateBD);
console.log(dateBD);
```

porque al llamar al constructor y pasarle la fecha te retornará una instancia `Date` con la fecha deseada

Comment: Bienvenido. Ya lo he explicado [en otras ocasiones](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5457/cu%c3%a1l-es-el-prop%c3%b3sito-del-foro-o-dicho-de-otra-manera-c%c3%b3mo-puedo-mejorar-mis#comment23983_5457). **Este sitio no es un foro**. En una respuesta tienes que plantear una solución. Aquí claramente estás pidiendo información y eso se hace en los comentarios de la pregunta. Lo sé, aún no tienes [el privilegio de comentar](/help/privileges/comment). Pero eso no significa que esté bien hacer preguntas donde debería haber una respuesta.

Comment: Contiene la fecha en formato string, arriba en la imagen esta, hecho un console log con la variable en tipo string y luego otro ya convertida y me sale el Nan

Comment: Eduardo, para que empieces a ganar punto intenta poner esta respuesta en tu pregunta: El problema se debe a que quieres crear un objeto Date usando la función Date.parse, la solucion seria llamar al contructor de Date: data=Date(dataBD); porque al llamar al constructor y pasarle la fecha te retornará un objeto Date con la fecha deseada.

Comment: Muchas gracias Daniel, soy nuevo y no estoy familiarizado con el foro aun.

Comment: Eduardo disculpa, llevo algo de tiempo sin usar JS

Comment: De hecho, este sitio **no es un foro** (y te lo aclararon varias veces, de hecho) :) Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento de [es.so].